# What is the best approach when it comes to forming a method?

Tags: c#

I apologise for the bad title. This is what I'm curious about:

Is it better or worse to do the following:

```
public DPRFileContent(IDPRFile dprFile) {

    if (dprFile == null) {
        throw new Exception("DPR file parameter can not be null. Method[DPRFileContent]");
    }

    this.dprFile = dprFile;
    getFileContent();
}
```

OR

```
public DPRFileContent(IDPRFile dprFile) {

    if (dprFile == null) {
        throw new Exception("DPR file parameter can not be null. Method[DPRFileContent]");
    } else {

        this.dprFile = dprFile;
        getFileContent();
    }
}
```

It may be down to just the coding style that one prefers but as I'm a pretty amateur programmer I'm really interested in what more experienced programmers would prefer.

Thanks.

Comment: Neither, there should be events for 1.When the content is found 2.For when not the content is found. Throwing exceptions that client can not do anything about handling them serves no purpose

Comment: I voted this question to be closed because it is primarily opinion based. However, my opinion (*based on you example*) is to go with the first method without `else`, since it is redundant (*in your example*) and using it increases the nesting of your code so reduces it's readability.

Comment: @Christos : neither case is better than other, they are both non OOP archaic procedural code, using events would render any arguments for using of either approach mute.

Answer (score 1):

First one is preferable, else is not needed. Also, you can use [Code Contracts](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ec7db13-3363-46c9-851f-1ce455f66970)

```
Contract.Requires(dprFile != null);
```

Comment: +1 for reference to code contracts, but that is still archaic non OOP code, I would recommend using events instead of if else.